# Why my grid layout is not occupying complete width

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am having a grid which contains six rows(each row is a stack Layout).

Inside my fifth row(i.e 5th stack layout) I am having a grid.I gave 100% width for that grid, but that grid is not occupying 100% of the width.

How do I fix this problem?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Grid Width="100%">
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Vertical">
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you please add a simplified XAML code?

Comment: you may try removing the stack panel and you can use *Grid.Row* on *Grid* and that would fix the issue

Comment: Get rid of the `StackPanel`, and place the inner `Grid` directly in the parent `Grid`.

Answer (score 2):

I think , you can try removing the stack panel and you can use Grid.Row on Grid and that would fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't see percentages used in UWP before and even think it is not a valid syntax. I think you should use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` instead to stretch the `Grid` to full width.

Answer (score 1):

@Martin Zikmund and @Durai Amuthan.H's suggestions were all correct. The `Width=100%` in UWP XAML layout doesn't support.

If you want to make the Grid's has the same width as the StackPanel and automatically resize when the window resized, you could also remove the `Width` directly like the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Grid Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="abc"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Vertical">
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```